# cannot logon time and date do not match server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008

For the past two days, some of my users get an error that they cannot logon to their workstations (Windows 7) because the time and date do not match the server (Server 2008 R2). They *DO* match. The only "fix" I have been able to find is to reboot the server and wait about 3 minutes before users try logging on again. If the users logon before 8:30am (or somewhere in there), they can get in with no problem. This is the strangest thing I have seen. Nothing in logs seems to indicate a problem other than "Missing IP" errors show up around the time users cannot logon. The server has static IP.

Any ideas?

Comment: Query one of those workstations and see where it is getting its time from.

Comment: Although the clocks match, do the time zones match? For example, is the server time 8:30am GMT while the clients' time is 8:30am EST?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to specify that. Yes, Time Zones match as well. Thanks for your reply! If I ever figure it out, I'll post a solution and/or give props to the person who solves the problem.

Comment: Active Directory time synchronization is time zone/DST agnostic.